# On covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation, differentiation

Let us denote a 1 form on manifold M with $\eta$ which in a chart looks like $\eta=\eta_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ where $\eta_{\mu}$ are smooth functions on M. Now given the coordinate vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$, $$\nabla_{\nu}\eta\equiv\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}}\eta$$ is a (0,1) tensor field, i.e, another 1 form. so, it makes sense to talk about $(\nabla_{\nu}\eta)_{\mu}$ and I can see that (after acting $\nabla_{\nu}\eta$ on a coordinate vector field) the following holds
$$(\nabla_{\nu}\eta)_{\mu}=\nabla_{\nu}\eta_{\mu}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho}.$$ Note that since $\eta_{\mu}$ are smooth functions on M, $\nabla_{\nu}\eta_{\mu}=\eta_{\mu,\nu}$ are ordinary partial derivatives of $\eta_{\mu}$. The above equation can be rewritten as: $$\eta_{\mu;\nu}=\eta_{\mu,\nu}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\rho}.$$ My question is why in the physics/general relativity literature then  $\nabla_{\nu}\eta_{\mu}$ denotes the covariant derivative of the 1 form $\eta$ along the coordinate vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$? The covariant derivative of $\eta$ along $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$, denoted by $\nabla_{\nu}\eta$ is a (0,1) tensor field whose components are denoted by $(\nabla_{\nu}\eta)_{\mu}$ (the left hand side of the second equation above) where as $\nabla_{\nu}\eta_{\mu}$ are mere partial derivatives of the component functions $\eta_{\mu}$.

Comment: That's just abuse of notation. When they write $\nabla_\nu\eta_\mu$, they mean $(\nabla_\nu\eta)_\mu$.

Comment: I guess, then, they denote $(\nabla_{\nu}X)^\mu$ by $\nabla_{\nu}X^{\mu}$ for vector field $X=X^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ as well which to me is a serious abuse of notation and may lead to terrible confusions.

Comment: Yes, they do.  (two more characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually $\nabla_\mu$ is not taken to be an operator by itself. Or, you can take it to be an operator, with the understanding that certain indices are *tensor indices* and certain indices are *counting indices*, and when $\nabla_\mu$ acts on something with tensor indices, it means "take the *abstract* covariant derivative, then take the components".

So $\nabla_\mu A^\nu$ is shorthand notation for $(\nabla A)_{\mu}^{\ \nu}$.

A convention that is probably not widespread, but what I personally use (if I have to mix Ricci calculus with modern differential geometry) is to use two, separate notation for covariant derivatives. The $\nabla_X Y$ notation for invariant notation and $\nabla_\mu A^\nu$ for component notation. In this sense, $$ \nabla_\mu A^\nu=\partial_\mu A^\nu +\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\sigma}A^\sigma $$ but $$ \nabla_{\partial_\mu}A^\nu=\partial_\mu A^\nu. $$

The two dont mix in the sense that I'll never write something as $$ \nabla_\mu A $$ where $ A=A_\mu dx^\mu $, and I'll never write something as $\nabla_X A^\mu$, unless I actually mean $X(A^\mu)=X^\nu\partial_\nu A^\mu$.